# Excel "master column" to reorganize rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, metadata, spreadsheet

Any help is greatly appreciated,

I am trying to compile many tables in excel. I wan't the list on the left to be the master list, and the list on the right to be ordered according to matching the C value on the left.

(before)

- [a1][b1][**c1**]        - [x3][y3][c3]
- [a2][b2][**c2**]      -  [x1][y1][c1]
- [a3][b3][**c3**]     -  [x2][y2][c2]

.....

(after)

- [a1][b1][**c1**]        - [x1][y1][**c1**]
- [a2][b2][**c2**]      -  [x2][y2][**c2**]
- [a3][b3][**c3**]     -  [x3][y3][**c3**]

The only variable that is consistent across table is C, and they should match exactly. The tricky thing is... when I add the second table to excel it is essentially "disorganized." I am hoping to reorganize it immediately so the C column's will line up across the board. The variable "c" is a string of characters and numbers.

I am later hoping to compare things like [a1] to [x1] and have a formula create a new table based on the differences of these variables

Comment: You can use `vlookup()` to align items from the second table with rows in the first table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I came up with a solution, however it uses vba not an excel formula, so it may not suit your needs

What this function does is look at the column on the left hand side (your master) and read the value out of it. It then looks for the same text in the right hand side (key column). When it finds a match it swaps the data between the two rows

```
a1, b2, c1, x3, y3, c3  <--- starting with this row
a2, b2, c2, x1, y1, c1
a3, b3, c3, x2, y2, c2
```

so in your example we are looking for **c1** it finds it in **row 2** so it trades the values from row 1 to row 2 and from row 2 to row 1

```
a1, b2, c1, x1, y1, c1  <--- after swap
a2, b2, c2, x3, y3, c3  <--- after swap
a3, b3, c3, x2, y2, c2
```

The next iteration it is looking for **c2**. it finds it in **row 3** so it trades the two rows

```
a1, b2, c1, x1, y1, c1  
a2, b2, c2, x2, y2, c2  <--- after swap
a3, b3, c3, x3, y3, c3  <--- after swap
```

now your list is sorted! I tried to document the code the best I could. Just change the values in the top portion

```
Sub MoveDataRowsToMatchMasterList()
    data_sheet = "Sheet2"   'the name of the sheet with all the data
    mastercol = "c"         'this is the left hand side
    keycol = "f"            'this is the right hand side
    data_col_start = "d"    'this is the first data column on the right hand side
    data_col_end = keycol   'this is the last data column on the right hand side

    row_start = 2           'the first row of data
    row_end = 4             'the last row of data

    temp_sheet = "temporary_sheet" 'this is a temporary sheet that will store intermediate values
                                   'make sure the name doesnt match an existing sheet

    '---------------------- end of user configuration -------------------
    Application.StatusBar = "Sorting list, please be patient"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'adds temporary sheet
    Sheets.Add Before:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = temp_sheet

    'goes through all the rows of data
    For curr_row = row_start To row_end
        'initializes value
        row_with_match = 0

        'reads the value from the master column (left hand side)
        master_key = Sheets(data_sheet).Range(mastercol & curr_row).Value

        'searches all the rows until it finds value/key (from the right hand side)
        'that matches the master key
        'notice we start at the curr_row (we assume the rows above curr_row are
        'already sorted properly)
        For search_row = curr_row To row_end

            'reads the value from the key column (right hand side)
            curr_key = Sheets(data_sheet).Range(keycol & search_row).Value

            'if they match we found our key
            If StrComp(master_key, curr_key) = 0 Then
                row_with_match = search_row
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        'MsgBox (master_key & " matched row " & row_with_match)

        'copies the data at the current row and puts it in the temporary sheet
        Sheets(data_sheet).Range(data_col_start & curr_row & ":" & data_col_end & curr_row).Copy
        Sheets(temp_sheet).Select
        Range(data_col_start & curr_row).Select
        Sheets(temp_sheet).Paste


        'copies the matching data and pastes it where it belongs
        Sheets(data_sheet).Range(data_col_start & row_with_match & ":" & data_col_end & row_with_match).Copy
        Sheets(data_sheet).Select
        Range(data_col_start & curr_row).Select
        Sheets(data_sheet).Paste

        'copies the data from the temporary sheet to where the match was found
        Sheets(temp_sheet).Range(data_col_start & curr_row & ":" & data_col_end & curr_row).Copy
        Sheets(data_sheet).Select
        Range(data_col_start & row_with_match).Select
        Sheets(data_sheet).Paste
    Next

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    'deletes temporary sheet
    Sheets(temp_sheet).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.StatusBar = ""
End Sub
```

if this solves your problem please mark as the solution

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on what your actually looks like but perhaps you can transcribe from this illustrated version. First select column E:H and right-click, Insert to push them off to the right.

[image: Reorder Data]

As I perceive it, your lookup column is to the right of the values to be returned so an `INDEX(MATCH())` pair would be better suited than a `VLOOKUP` as the latter demands that the lookup column be the same or to the left of the values to be returned.

The formula in the new E2 is,

`=IF(LEN($G2), INDEX(I:I, MATCH($C2,$K:$K, 0)), "")`

This will not immediately show a value but will be fixed later. Fill right one column then put this formula in G2,

`=IFERROR(INDEX(K:K, MATCH($C2,$K:$K, 0)), "")`

With E2:G2 now showing values (or not if C2 was not found), fill down as necessary.